# How can i use IAM in AWS to provide temporary security credentails

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

IAM has a component of service called `Simple Token Service (STS)`. It allows you to create temporary access through SDK/ API to access AWS resources without having the need to create dedicated credentials. These STS tokens have a user-defined life period and those are destroyed post that. People use this service for accessing content from mobile devices such as Android/ IOS Apps.

But i don't know how to use this service.

Any help or support is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

STS and IAM go hand in hand, and is real simple to use. Since you have not given a use case, please allow me to explain a few things before we get in coding.

**Note: I code in PHP and the SDK version is 3.**

The idea of STS is to create some `tokens` which allows the bearer to do certain actions without you (the owner or the grantee) compromising your own credentials. Which type of STS you are going to use depends on what you want to do. [Possible actions are listed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

> E.g.1: Typically, you use `AssumeRole` for cross-account access or
>   federation. Imagine that you own multiple accounts and need to access
>   resources in each account. You could create long-term credentials in
>   each account to access those resources. However, managing all those
>   credentials and remembering which one can access which account can be
>   time consuming. Instead, you can create one set of long-term
>   credentials in one account and then use temporary security credentials
>   to access all the other accounts by assuming roles in those accounts.
>
> E.g.2: Typically, you use `GetSessionToken` if you want to use MFA to protect
>   programmatic calls to specific AWS APIs like Amazon EC2 StopInstances.

Let us assume you have an IAM user and you want to create many temporary credentials for that user, each credential with a time frame of **15 minutes**. Then you will write the following code:

```
$stsClient = \Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::createClient('sts', array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$awsTempCreds = $stsClient->getSessionToken(array(
    'DurationSeconds' => 900
));
```

**Points to note:**

1. Credentials that are created by IAM users are valid for the duration that you specify, from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to a maximum of 129600 seconds (36 hours), with a default of 43200 seconds (12 hours); credentials that are created by using account credentials can range from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to a maximum of 3600 seconds (1 hour), with a default of 1 hour.
2. In the above example I am getting `$stsClient` using `AWS Facade` which is part of Laravel framework. It is up to you how you get hold of `$stsClient` by passing credentials. Read this [installation guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/) on how to instantiate your `$stsClient`.
3. Since `STS` is a global resource i.e. it does not require you to be in a specific region, you MUST ALWAYS set the region to `us-east-1`. If your region is set to anything else, you will get errors like **`should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-1'`**.
4. There is no limit on how many temporary credentials you make.
5. These credentials will have the SAME permissions from which `Account/IAM` they are derived from.

Above code returns a set of temporary credentials for an AWS account or IAM user. The credentials consist of an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token, plus a few other information such as expiry time.

You can now give these temporary credentials to someone else. Let us say I gave this to my friend who happens to use the `Javascript API`. He now can write codes like this:

```
<script>
var accessKey = '<?php echo $credentials["AccessKeyId"] ?>';
var accessToken = '<?php echo $credentials["SecretAccessKey"] ?>';
var accessSessionToken = '<?php echo $credentials["SessionToken"] ?>';

AWS.config.update({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: accessKey,
        secretAccessKey: accessToken,
        sessionToken: accessSessionToken
    },
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

var bucket = new AWS.S3();
var file = fileChooser.files[0];
var params = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};

bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
}).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
    console.log('Progress:', evt.loaded, '/', evt.total); 
});
</script>
```

**What this script does?**

1. Creates a new client using temporary credentials.
2. Uploads a very large file (more than 100MB) to `mybucket` using `Multipart Upload`.

**Similarly, you can do operations on any AWS resource as long as you temporary credentials have permission to do so.** Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

STS is little tough to understand (need to put real time in reading it). I will try (yes try!) to explain as simple as possible. The service is useful if you need to do things like this:

1. You have a bucket on S3. You have say 100 users who you would like to upload files to this bucket. It is obvious that you should not distribute your AWS key/secret to all of them. Here comes STS. You can use STS to allow these users to write to a "portion" (say a folder by their google-id) of the bucket for a "limited time" (say 1 hr). You achieve this by doing the required setup (IAM, S3 policy and STS-AssumeRoles) and sending them a URL (which they use to upload). In this case, you can also use the Web Identity Federation to authenticate users by Google/FB/Amazon.com. So with no backend code, this workflow is achievable. [Web Identity Federation Playground](https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) gives you a sense of how this works.
2. You have an AWS account and want somebody else (another AWS user) to help you manage this. Here again you give the other user limited-time access to a selected portion of your AWS resource without sharing the Key/secret
3. Assume you have a DynamoDB setup with a row of data per your app-user. Here you need to ensure a given user can write only on his row of data and not others. You can use STS to setup stuff like this.

A complete example is here:
Web Identity Federation with Mobile Applications : Articles & Tutorials : Amazon Web Services : http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313

More reading:
Creating Temporary Security Credentials for Mobile Apps Using Identity Providers - AWS Security Token Service : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingWIF.html

Comment: can you please explain what is this service all about and how to get the things done

Comment: I want to use this service for aws resources such as ec2 s3 ebs vol etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have edited the above post to include more detailed response as feedback from others indicated. Requesting the undelete as well !